# Midrash Meam Loez Purim

Tags: midrash, purim

We don't have good midrashim books here in our town.

Do we have the **story of Purim** with good midrashim in English on the net?

Comment: You want meam loez in English or any midrashim

Answer (score 2):

**Chabad.org** has a online (all English) "[Megillah With In-Depth, Side by Side Commentary](https://www.chabad.org/holidays/in-depth/default_cdo/aid/39643/jewish/Megillah-with-Commentary.htm)" which you may find useful.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to the party but if anyone sees this before next Purim here is a good book that goes through the entire Purim story with the midrashim and really added to my understanding of the Purim story. (You can order this on most judaica stores websites)

Let my Nation Live

https://www.judaicaplace.com/let-my-nation-live-hardcover/9781578197828/

Answer (score 0):

There is in [Otzar Hachachma](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=105676&width=0&scroll=0&udid=0&pagenum=1) (first 40 pages are free, but the rest must be paid for).

Comment: The OP revised his question and asked for English now (I know, it is somewhat frustrating to answer only to see the question invalidate the answer...)